# I hosted my code on amazon EC2 and didnt point to a domain. and My payment gateway doesn't seem to work even in a test account

Tags: amazon-ec2

Should I point a domain for the payment gateway to work?
I did migrate my code to my other server with has a domain attacked to it and the payment gateway works. What do you think is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you said

> I did migrate my code to my other server with has a domain attacked to
>   it and the payment gateway works

Maybe there is an issue with redirecting to the payment portal, your payment portal needs HTTPS whereas EC2 without a domain is HTTP.

One should always use HTTPS in payment portal because credit card numbers will be stolen while in transit. This is one reason for must HTTPS in payment portal.